# Google Chrome подскакивает

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Google Chrome в развёрнутом виде (не fullscreen), при наведении на любую ссылку, смещается на пару пикселей вниз а потом обратно. При этом изначально он как бы вылазит за верхний край экрана (видно на скриншоте).

[image: верхний край браузера]

ОС: Windows 10 x64
Разрешение: 1920х1080 (16:10)

Переустанавливать пробовал, запускать в инкогнито режиме (без дополнений) тоже, разрешение менял — не помогает ничего.

Comment: Может у вас на мониторе картинка немного уехала? Какой тип монитора - ноутбук, стационарный; lcd / плазма / ЭЛТ? Какая видеокарта? Через что подключен (vga / какой-то цифровой)? Какие драйвера установлены? Корректировать / автонастройку монитора пробовали делать?

Comment: У меня ноутбук с 15.6" IPS 1920х1080 16:10, дискретное видео nVidia GeForce GT 940MX, 2 Gb, не знаю в чем была беда, но вылечить вышло только установкой кастомной темы. Может эта версия хрома просто не дружит с WUXGA.

Comment: Так же помогает отключение аппаратного ускорения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправилось установкой другой темы оформления https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-b...
С темой по умолчанию, скачки возвращаются.